# 小数点以下を含む値と含まない値があるデータから、数値のみを取り出す方法

Tags: python, 正規表現

次のような単位(畳)が入っている面積xから、,単位(畳)を除いた数値の変数spaceを作りたいと考えています。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['3畳', '4.5畳']})
```

次のような正規表現を使った場合には、

```
df["space"] = df["x"].str.extract(r'([0-9]*)畳')
```

次のように変換されます。(->は変換後を示します。)
3畳->  3
4.5畳-> 5

小数点以下の場合を考慮した場合には、

```
df["space"] = df["x"].str.extract(r'([0-9]+\.[0-9]*)畳')
```

4.5畳のみしか変換されません。
3畳-> nan
4.5畳-> 4.5

次のように、変換させた変数spaceを作成したいです。
3畳-> 3
4.5畳-> 4.5

どなたか、ご教示頂けるとありがたいです。

Comment: `df["space"] = df["x"].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)畳')` としても良さそうです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。参考になります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下はどうでしょうか。

```
df["space"] = df["x"].str.extract(r'([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)畳')
print(df)
```

実行結果は以下になります。

```
      x space
0    3畳     3
1  4.5畳   4.5
```

以下は、[正規表現のシンタックス](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/re.html)からの抜粋です。

> `?` 
>   直前にある RE に作用して、 RE を 0 回か 1 回繰り返したものにマッチさせるようにします。例えば ab? は 'a' あるいは'ab' にマッチします。

Comment: うまくいきました。また「?」の説明も付けて頂きまして、ありがとうございます。この使い方を、覚えることができました。

Answer (score 1):

単位を削除したい場合は、`strip()`を使うのが簡単で処理も速いです。

```
df["space"] = df["x"].str.rstrip('畳')
```

Comment: ご教示くださいまして、ありがとうございます。これは存じませんでした。