# Python の正規表現で . (ドット) を含む数値のみを抽出したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

文字列から、値部分のみを抽出したいのですが、実現するための正規表現が上手く書けず困っています。

※とあるデータのなかに、本来は【数値】のカラムがあるのですが、場合によっては「#」や「)」といった文字列が一緒に含まれているレコードがあるため、csv読み込み時に文字列と読み込まれてしまうので、数値部分のみを抽出したいと考えています。

例えば、"#5.3" や "5.3)" という文字列から、5.3 のみを抽出したいイメージです。

以下が試しているコードですが、こちらだと数字のみが抽出されてしまうため、「.（ドット）」を含めて抽出したいです。

```
import re
s = "5.3)"
result = res = re.sub(r"\D", "", s)
print(result)
# 53
```

アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: こちら [小数点以下を含む値と含まない値があるデータから、数値のみを取り出す方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/46951/26370) と同件あるいは類似かもしれません。

Comment: 対象の数値に符号(`+-`)や指数表記用の `eE` が含まれる事はありますか？

Comment: kunif様：ありがとうございます！該当記事確認させていただきます！

Comment: metropolis様：ご確認いただいた内容は含まれません！（下記cubick様のアドバイスを参考に、解決できました）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

不要な文字の対象に `.` は含まれないと仮定して、例えば以下のような書き方ができると思います。

```
result = res = re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", s)
```

Comment: このような書き方は知りませんでした、、ありがとうございました！